# Is it wise to stay in a job where I'm coasting without serious responsibilities for a long period of time?

Tags: job-change, job-description, resignation

About 8 months ago I left my job of about 4 years and began working for a new company. A few months after I joined my new company restructured and my primary job responsibility was outsourced. However, the company has kept me around doing relatively minor tasks and largely twiddling my thumbs. On the upside, my salary is fairly good, and, well, the job isn't too stressful. On the downside, I'm not really learning much, and there's little satisfaction - I'm not building or creating anything lasting and it's difficult for me to contribute in a meaningful way to company operations.

How bad is it to 'coast' on an easy, but  unfullfilling and unchallenging job? I'm in the genetics & software business, so there are certainly other job possibilities, though they may require a move out of state.

Comment: I would assume that at some point the company will figure out that they outsourced your job responsibilities and that they are paying you way more than they need to for your new job role.  At that point, you'll find yourself looking for a new job.  That's going to be more difficult the longer you've been twiddling your thumbs rather than improving your skills.

Comment: At the very least do whatever you can to improve yourself. Learn new things, decide for yourself what to build and build it. Very few people have the opportunity to spend a few months learning, so use that time.

Comment: You most likely will be let go eventually. easier to find a job when have one, start looking. Don't count on unemployment insurance, that stuff runs out fast and before know it, will be working at a gas station just to keep the lights on in the house (know from experience)

Answer (score 4):

One of three things will interrupt your coasting: they let go of you (fire, layoff, restructure, etc.),  you leave them, or you make yourself useful. Which is preferable to you and which do you have control over?

**They let you go:** If you are "coasting" for, say, 24 months or longer, you're going to have trouble interviewing off of your work experience and may run the risk of outdated skills (IMO people confuse "not keeping up with technology" with "not showing upward trajectory", if that matters).

**You leave them:** Most people prefer looking for a new job when they already have one. There is no urgency which gives you both time to shop and leverage to negotiate. Perhaps you can use this time to find an opportunity close to home that might be very hard to find when you're unemployed and have pressure to find a new job very quickly.

**You stay and work hard:**  I don't know your situation but you might be wrong that you're useless. Just find something to do. Add value. You have unlimited time and pay to make use of yourself. It's a good time to be entrepreneurial within your firm. Perhaps your boss fought to keep you because whether you have a primary project or not you're a hard worker and smart to boot. This is more likely than you think.

Answer (score 4):

Continually coasting is dangerous. The company may just decide that you're not worth it anymore and lay you off. If you aren't prepared for this, that can seriously mess with your life.

You should either look for a new job or work on finding a way to add value to your current company. It won't last forever and you have to be prepared for when it ends.

Comment: You probably should **both** look for a job and try to add value while there.  Even if you plan to leave, you might as well make the most of it while you are there (and finding a new job is never certain).  And even if you don't want to leave, you should consider your job at risk until you have found a role where you are definitely needed in the company (so good to start at least some job searching).

Comment: It probably won't be personal, but the coasters will be let go when a purge is needed. Some tips to drag out the inevitable: always have something in your hands when walking around, don't play on internet (reading pdf novels can be hidden easily with not much log reports), go to lunch late or at odd times but also come back even later, keep the 1.5 hours vague and always changing. continue to be on time in morning.